# Google OAuth using MVC - how to keep the login session valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, model-view-controller, oauth, google-oauth

I'm using Google OAuth to login users to my site. Google authentication is working and I'm able to get the basic info along with access token, refresh token, etc. I'm storing the provider, userid and email in a table. So, when a user logs in through google, I check the table for the userid, if it exists, I take them to the index page. If they don't exist in the table, I take them to the register page. My question is, how can I keep the login session valid across pages for the logged in user? Should I use a session? What would be the best approach?

Comment: Do you mean how would you keep your user logged in across pages, like a cookie?

Comment: @victor Yes, correct.